TailwindCSS - avoid purge of generative classes
I would like to prevent Tailwind from purging some classes. They are generated in the component eg.
className=`text-${size}`

Tailwind does not know it will result in text-sm, text-base and text-lg even if size variable is a union of
type Size = "sm" | "base" | "lg";

Is it possible to achieve that without using full classes elsewhere in the code?
The only solution I managed to find is:
const sizeClass = size === "sm" ? "text-sm" : size === "lg" ? "text-lg" : "text-base";
(...)
className={sizeClass}


Although Tailwind doesn't recommend dynamic classes for this reason, you can still generate them if you add them to the safelist in your Tailwind config:
module.exports = {
  ...
  safelist: [
    'text-sm',
    'text-base',
    'text-lg'
  ],
  ...
}

You can also use a regex instead of individual strings. For more info, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Thank you ❤️ couldn't find it in the search

Simplify your code, and avoid string concatenation entirely. Then this problem never occurs.
className=`${textSize}`

type Size = "text-sm" | "text-base" | "text-lg";

